# Passing value from modal iframe to parent iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hello I’ve a data in a modal iframe (let's call frame 1)  and I should pass it in a iframe (rte_ticket_message ) cointained in a parent window.

In the modal iframe (frame 1) with the javascript

```
parent.document.getElementById("detailed_req").innerHTML=”test”;
```

I cannot pass the value to the iframe contained in the parten window.

In the parent window I have the iframe id=“rte_ticket_message” containing a body with

id="detailed_req"  where I want to put the value I've stored in the iframe1.

Here the structure of the parent winow with iframe id=rte_ticket_message

```
<div class="container">
<iframe id="rte_ticket_message" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">
<html>
<head>
<body id="detailed_req" class="editorWYSIWYG" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px"> 
</html>
</iframe>
```

Please Insert Relevant Notes:

Someone have any suggestion on the script I should use?
Thanks

F.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using cookies `document.cookie` command.